# php spredsheet outputs currupted file

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

Hi below is my simple code for generating excel file:

```
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello World !');
ob_end_clean();
header( "Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel" );
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.xlsx"');
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
ob_end_clean();
$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
$writer->save('php://output');
```

but when I open file it shows file corrupted error.
[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to do things right, however, I'll share my code, try it, it might be useful for you.

```
<?php
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$fileName.'"');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
        $writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xls');
        $writer->save('php://output');
        exit;
?>
```

Comment: thank you for your response but it's not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like the wrong character set is being used.

Try to change

```
header( "Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel" );
```

To

```
header( 'Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8' );
```

P.s. Note the capital **T** in `Content-Type`

Comment: still facing same issue.